# Jetson nano poor performance with yolov5n and cuda activated

Tags: yolov5, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm testing Yolov5n with a Jetson nano B01 device (4GB).

For this purpose I'm using a docker version from this repo: [repo](https://github.com/otamajakusi/dockerfile-yolov5-jetson)

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.7.1

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      git \
      python3.8 python3.8-dev python3-pip \
      libopenmpi-dev libomp-dev libopenblas-dev libblas-dev libeigen3-dev

RUN python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3.8 -m pip install setuptools gdown

# pytorch 1.11.0
RUN gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1hs9HM0XJ2LPFghcn7ZMOs5qu5HexPXwM
RUN python3.8 -m pip install torch-*.whl

# torchvision 0.12.0
RUN gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1m0d8ruUY8RvCP9eVjZw4Nc8LAwM8yuGV
RUN python3.8 -m pip install torchvision-*.whl

RUN git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git
WORKDIR yolov5
RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY is_docker.patch .
RUN patch -p1 < is_docker.patch
```

I'm running docker from a default installation (SD Card, no SSD)

These are the results from a list of 640x640 car and bottle images:

```
root@25b13ebea957:/yolov5# python3.8 detect.py --weights yolov5n.pt --source data/images
detect: weights=['yolov5n.pt'], source=data/images, data=data/coco128.yaml, imgsz=[640, 640], conf_thres=0.25, iou_thres=0.45, max_det=1000, device=, view_img=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, nosave=False, classes=None, agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, visualize=False, update=False, project=runs/detect, name=exp, exist_ok=False, line_thickness=3, hide_labels=False, hide_conf=False, half=False, dnn=False, vid_stride=1
YOLOv5  v7.0-116-g5c91dae Python-3.8.0 torch-1.11.0a0+gitbc2c6ed CUDA:0 (NVIDIA Tegra X1, 3964MiB)

Downloading https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases/download/v7.0/yolov5n.pt to yolov5n.pt...
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3.87M/3.87M [00:01<00:00, 4.02MB/s]

Fusing layers...
YOLOv5n summary: 213 layers, 1867405 parameters, 0 gradients
image 1/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000002_jpg.rf.41c3bd80c13879da35da9cad8c672729.jpg: 640x640 1 parking meter, 174.0ms
image 2/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000006_jpg.rf.dd3940f860d6ade63e4247555fb1e559.jpg: 640x640 1 cake, 173.9ms
image 3/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000020_jpg.rf.668142e21ed24351ae6a8f5cc899817d.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.3ms
image 4/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000021_jpg.rf.98fce8efe88fd90a1ec0bd683243537c.jpg: 640x640 2 bottles, 173.9ms
image 5/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000028_jpg.rf.03e103667071f566385b6ff03e129069.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 173.6ms
image 6/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000040_jpg.rf.81e12357b61957bc7d01bb7b8fc06861.jpg: 640x640 1 surfboard, 1 bottle, 2 vases, 173.6ms
image 7/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000092_jpg.rf.1c4b4f1dc7da8b6ccf574a6067651a5e.jpg: 640x640 5 bottles, 173.9ms
image 8/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000132_jpg.rf.1a274621f0cf8c342962d61cefda313c.jpg: 640x640 4 bottles, 1 toothbrush, 175.4ms
image 9/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000141_png.rf.0753e47a2c4614522fb06ecc9e4b10bd.jpg: 640x640 2 bottles, 173.8ms
image 10/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000146_jpg.rf.ca6ce3dd4e5669fa6e15c1faf71918a4.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 174.0ms
image 11/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000163_jpg.rf.f62ee3d7bf9bbeff16f05dde8fcc2277.jpg: 640x640 1 car, 175.4ms
image 12/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000184_jpg.rf.8b2df2e255a02204a885aff64f01f366.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 13/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000222_jpg.rf.c633548eabfa4e6b2532805f370933f6.jpg: 640x640 3 bottles, 2 cups, 3 vases, 175.4ms
image 14/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000286_jpg.rf.da4093f2136eca656fe9d148eccec9c9.jpg: 640x640 2 bottles, 173.7ms
image 15/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000291_jpg.rf.f286e4547328ad1c912e66836500aaf6.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 16/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000312_jpg.rf.cb7cfb97cdcc8e451b49eaa491235325.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.2ms
image 17/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000313_jpg.rf.e80becce9fa85652a528abe75132f487.jpg: 640x640 8 bottles, 173.9ms
image 18/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000314_jpg.rf.e9f500142f276f218b0dacf24f6e1fb3.jpg: 640x640 1 vase, 175.3ms
image 19/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000322_jpeg.rf.eee821b3dbd466ed90abd9017551a801.jpg: 640x640 2 bottles, 173.6ms
image 20/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000330_jpg.rf.f5d384fb5d4bd3190b38ab48739b805b.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.6ms
image 21/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000332_jpg.rf.28cbcb6d54a5357cfba39d935a301bc9.jpg: 640x640 2 bottles, 1 cell phone, 175.6ms
image 22/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000344_jpg.rf.9146ceacbcc8a2fb9447b6b7bb8a84ea.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.9ms
image 23/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000363_jpg.rf.aa01a6501cc21dcc73e3bcddfe21ed56.jpg: 640x640 1 vase, 175.5ms
image 24/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000392_jpg.rf.1a206b2f0d8a62ffc20def8cfb6b9cb3.jpg: 640x640 1 toothbrush, 174.1ms
image 25/178 /yolov5/data/images/00000405_jpg.rf.9f358303c0f8e65921128c7bf42c6e9f.jpg: 640x640 1 vase, 173.9ms
image 26/178 /yolov5/data/images/03ea3ede0a_jpg.rf.fd4b0dd4844747e738e8784ed3ccaa20.jpg: 640x640 1 car, 1 bus, 1 parking meter, 175.4ms
image 27/178 /yolov5/data/images/144a1afb9a_jpg.rf.e0d8645f9e06c85e0e8e723cbdf9e429.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 28/178 /yolov5/data/images/165347b4f5_jpg.rf.14a66411f8f715399c8509b4eaf99c22.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.6ms
image 29/178 /yolov5/data/images/1dea3c8341_jpg.rf.85a5126880ee0f208d392692dfd0539a.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.5ms
image 30/178 /yolov5/data/images/293b21c8b3_jpg.rf.9bfb3c9a1762b104a49564208e3b79b4.jpg: 640x640 3 cups, 173.5ms
image 31/178 /yolov5/data/images/3b7255cc78_jpg.rf.425bae164f755ee345019c1d80c69744.jpg: 640x640 1 cup, 175.5ms
image 32/178 /yolov5/data/images/496c16bd93_jpg.rf.af4a82e06fd8ae79728e56cc766b8270.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 33/178 /yolov5/data/images/72278aeed6_jpg.rf.c32eb26ebbd96f63e0eccf571d24d170.jpg: 640x640 3 cups, 1 carrot, 1 cake, 175.4ms
image 34/178 /yolov5/data/images/725640810b_jpg.rf.4269e0f3c3b844d84f26fd79260c5ffa.jpg: 640x640 3 bottles, 3 cups, 173.7ms
image 35/178 /yolov5/data/images/733867bbc2_jpg.rf.9b1bc09e7cd5af85d307877c6f837e76.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 173.8ms
image 36/178 /yolov5/data/images/79838d8653_jpg.rf.15345de891ec0a9275ba63134eaff80b.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.2ms
image 37/178 /yolov5/data/images/8290e2aecd_jpg.rf.bb4f8c30ec1e7998623f89d6a587cf0b.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 38/178 /yolov5/data/images/95932a5b20_jpg.rf.49d1a36f9f48e14a4bbc4542ac3e0cac.jpg: 640x640 1 suitcase, 173.9ms
image 39/178 /yolov5/data/images/95a3b3d5b0_jpg.rf.8408804a7ad35077f74310e83f5dde1c.jpg: 640x640 2 cups, 2 cakes, 173.9ms
image 40/178 /yolov5/data/images/977156e83e_jpg.rf.30116803929852dabfebe2c6cbf0d69b.jpg: 640x640 3 vases, 173.8ms
image 41/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_103_jpg.rf.a3140d34b7f02d1d87e414d7637a8b4b.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.5ms
image 42/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_107_jpg.rf.19c701f0a06a91ec34aaae9aad3f2c02.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.9ms
image 43/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_118_jpg.rf.64d113f463c82dc54077707e3d020d29.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 44/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_120_jpg.rf.63fd9437bc7da2b527d09a203be433f6.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 45/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_129_jpg.rf.58bd16de956b94233ae9eb7cfcbb7734.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 1 car, 173.8ms
image 46/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_142_jpg.rf.1e4f57d8a3a012f746ac0b57d55f6345.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.2ms
image 47/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_157_jpg.rf.cb820c3f519af5c7c4fe8b56a1b77a33.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 48/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_171_jpg.rf.0d48a28aad8f47c58cea0c308d2ce18f.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 174.2ms
image 49/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_227_jpg.rf.6b3e03ba26aaa3f1ec671967c83f4f7c.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 174.0ms
image 50/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_233_jpg.rf.7bfebf3810d6e935f9743e13fa9de75a.jpg: 640x640 1 bus, 173.8ms
image 51/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_242_jpg.rf.9d4fbc41af98ebd901e43305b7d92569.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.6ms
image 52/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_262_jpg.rf.b31a699cd4fb180dd9b7f45852640c4d.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 174.1ms
image 53/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_269_jpg.rf.d3a4231587840257972b5c5e2d10b792.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 173.6ms
image 54/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_310_jpg.rf.5d46a46992b0bca830a042fdb2c77087.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 55/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_311_jpg.rf.f2917e7e573784563349e26180518184.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 56/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_323_jpg.rf.42845dc89eb03cf03c8767e41e3d4382.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.8ms
image 57/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_329_jpg.rf.12d35a39b88ba667e2ebd94379c739f8.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 58/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_352_jpg.rf.63c4dca15e37c5dfa22f1f6ddb46cebf.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.2ms
image 59/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_367_jpg.rf.c05e91c176107d403c0f7ad9cf23f824.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.9ms
image 60/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_395_jpg.rf.e656ac103475690d6974a5bba841a057.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 173.7ms
image 61/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_410_jpg.rf.0feb4478388515af2dabe2a9a6221396.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.2ms
image 62/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_427_jpg.rf.1bf37eda5d130c40b9b47cf5f5b58301.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.6ms
image 63/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_428_jpg.rf.3c6a8af7853bf350e75718cb23946c39.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.6ms
image 64/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_438_jpg.rf.b286f44a546d064b4c393c18911a1fa2.jpg: 640x640 1 car, 173.5ms
image 65/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_43_jpg.rf.057e62e740efa15f80c03fb97a76f457.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 66/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_466_jpg.rf.7933e3417f286bca774f8fe07edcec83.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.7ms
image 67/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_471_jpg.rf.d388e9b38c52938d84854ee9501bd68c.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 68/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_483_jpg.rf.50e6af4a98d3d667f37bc84e2f282bcf.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 176.6ms
image 69/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_485_jpg.rf.615c3bf5e7e3ad17dc6794b33ff161ca.jpg: 640x640 1 tv, 173.9ms
image 70/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_511_jpg.rf.3826aca002b178ea3daefafe20a8f4b0.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.9ms
image 71/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_524_jpg.rf.6b18d068254f168c6fc6387a74c75402.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.5ms
image 72/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_535_jpg.rf.588fc1a12f4bbde1d96252ee2fe2b447.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 73/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_556_jpg.rf.32f69fdc9064ce3c23acd8983b06775a.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.4ms
image 74/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_575_jpg.rf.f7196c7768bb7e99bbde031ab44c943e.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 174.7ms
image 75/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_582_jpg.rf.16cd74748cc94163753c004f9cc17e38.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.9ms
image 76/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_597_jpg.rf.b5817236068d00368060dd7986e3f54c.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.1ms
image 77/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_617_jpg.rf.ab6e6462532e940c5a87e1e73309fe7b.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 78/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_622_jpg.rf.fcfd74bc00783ceeb6fd5596798f890d.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.6ms
image 79/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_654_jpg.rf.284fe8e90a07dedf9853c773d8162832.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 80/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_65_jpg.rf.337416d200a3651adeae633c1591d642.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 81/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_667_jpg.rf.b1837a9e20f53be242cc621e54cec8b0.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 82/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_67_jpg.rf.effc9c239592948931fef53b94960380.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.6ms
image 83/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_710_jpg.rf.9d803a6c567d964e85703d6d286b49d1.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.4ms
image 84/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_718_jpg.rf.610b46bbb56b7ecfbd85344078e6581c.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 85/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_719_jpg.rf.93808980de8e9f58369850821888e663.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 86/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_73_jpg.rf.ec8df56ba9aa3c5d32f67439c11def63.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.9ms
image 87/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_744_jpg.rf.701ad842a87d677b1236b1f417faf91f.jpg: 640x640 1 traffic light, 175.3ms
image 88/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_760_jpg.rf.4879154f1d7fa0a8c9895272e82f95cc.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.0ms
image 89/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_789_jpg.rf.2c7e63e9182b27aa7f95150b3b66c8a0.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 174.1ms
image 90/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_796_jpg.rf.81dd7f247104c3f682d96b58582e3b2d.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 174.2ms
image 91/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_800_jpg.rf.9a599c861ee9b7a53af5ce4193377510.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 92/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_817_jpg.rf.f6df4fb60fd3717fcfb693f1d649b162.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.3ms
image 93/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_822_jpg.rf.c2d123175a8ea14215f02c9a1c447885.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.9ms
image 94/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_824_jpg.rf.13ca71bb6588f11a32f8186fead3eefc.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 174.3ms
image 95/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_828_jpg.rf.e611245ac1c4a0b2916508558938c8f4.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 96/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_836_jpg.rf.89de262510723ccbe175b790cb357c75.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 97/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_844_jpg.rf.32205fbe01479b9c76b6852672f9d255.jpg: 640x640 1 traffic light, 175.5ms
image 98/178 /yolov5/data/images/R_850_jpg.rf.9bcdca851abd44dc5e973100fc6a75aa.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 99/178 /yolov5/data/images/a154e31fe6_jpg.rf.5b66585559baa1322d4b5cc71e001c0e.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.7ms
image 100/178 /yolov5/data/images/a4e50ecbed_jpg.rf.dde1bc6908d4c2d1471c080508d7ee6f.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.8ms
image 101/178 /yolov5/data/images/acca057365_jpg.rf.8ecbe957192bafc13d400d97e466a791.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.9ms
image 102/178 /yolov5/data/images/ba16ec227a_jpg.rf.d16312e19f402e73b6b9180b51d922b3.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 175.5ms
image 103/178 /yolov5/data/images/bus.jpg: 640x480 4 persons, 1 bus, 135.9ms
image 104/178 /yolov5/data/images/cd4b64e1fb_jpg.rf.b51b79f65aa4d912966e0964e82ce92c.jpg: 640x640 1 orange, 173.8ms
image 105/178 /yolov5/data/images/eff91468db_jpg.rf.828693b562d8590d4d58fa655d2394fe.jpg: 640x640 (no detections), 173.6ms
image 106/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene00019_png.rf.e0766b2d34d4a6f948615c3ac6963265.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 8 cars, 3 buss, 173.9ms
image 107/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09495_png.rf.ab4e13fa24076feeee2d34f48517e0d3.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 5 cars, 1 truck, 173.7ms
image 108/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09496_png.rf.1b02bc511e308bbee1db664fa9a16ace.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 5 cars, 1 truck, 175.4ms
image 109/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09498_png.rf.5036160da3c11dbad737e770d1d3e602.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 5 cars, 1 truck, 173.5ms
image 110/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09500_png.rf.8404d4fbbded2342ad7ba0d53773ebf2.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 5 cars, 1 truck, 174.6ms
image 111/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09509_png.rf.b8263f519d2f424fcf6e59b41bb84f1f.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 6 cars, 1 truck, 175.5ms
image 112/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09515_png.rf.dda67a9cea5490d5577ea1e3d3979d90.jpg: 640x640 3 persons, 5 cars, 1 umbrella, 173.8ms
image 113/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09516_png.rf.a386ffdd24fb4efd118a4aa1cad8757d.jpg: 640x640 6 cars, 1 umbrella, 175.3ms
image 114/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09518_png.rf.0f3c4c99ef3eda67ce2ff87fe4717409.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 5 cars, 173.7ms
image 115/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09520_png.rf.782b4dd7aa3fad0595f19aa9da5bb20d.jpg: 640x640 5 cars, 1 truck, 1 umbrella, 173.7ms
image 116/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09522_png.rf.28f1821e09927a64004ddbc374f9823f.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 4 cars, 1 truck, 1 umbrella, 175.8ms
image 117/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09530_png.rf.d559251926cfcd89f9d211a8beb4f7ab.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 3 cars, 1 truck, 173.8ms
image 118/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09531_png.rf.09abc26f32b2fc3de830bd7f239161e6.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 3 cars, 1 truck, 173.8ms
image 119/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09532_png.rf.b0197674f666401c30a44726bcde8485.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 173.6ms
image 120/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09535_png.rf.de8d53cb963409a74896594c03020c2a.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 5 cars, 174.0ms
image 121/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09536_png.rf.e910e7bf6f31c3a14e96782d28c6b860.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 1 airplane, 1 truck, 1 umbrella, 175.2ms
image 122/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09541_png.rf.7afde91d0f691a37ef072933bc498c4e.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 5 cars, 173.9ms
image 123/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09546_png.rf.832211b3c2645e95f2b9f81adc1e1cb4.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 1 truck, 173.9ms
image 124/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09547_png.rf.e0f40ab93a68a1a6bfca5043d0580ee0.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 1 truck, 173.7ms
image 125/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09556_png.rf.0835a0fc45c315e769adb382dfafe754.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 1 truck, 173.7ms
image 126/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09567_png.rf.621dbc0d981a64c5d1fbe7c8d1c76c23.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 1 car, 175.7ms
image 127/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09570_png.rf.1fdd0d8bf5a4241588bf092050d72973.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 2 cars, 174.3ms
image 128/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09572_png.rf.d33accd317e6a07f74dfc0c312c567cf.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 173.8ms
image 129/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09579_png.rf.c4458a73875a0c182fa962993361eb82.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 2 cars, 173.7ms
image 130/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09582_png.rf.7d2065bc8b1d2594c749ffa41d29d53c.jpg: 640x640 3 cars, 1 motorcycle, 173.7ms
image 131/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09583_png.rf.6e5a4cc3c344704b66a0da3ca2c6cc0c.jpg: 640x640 3 cars, 175.2ms
image 132/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09589_png.rf.ae8911a21a097556b71f9de5b4c8f107.jpg: 640x640 3 cars, 174.3ms
image 133/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09593_png.rf.7dcf4ed96862e0023e587d01dee5a334.jpg: 640x640 2 cars, 1 truck, 173.8ms
image 134/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09594_png.rf.4c2638da794b61ef172bf9ee718a9d48.jpg: 640x640 2 cars, 1 truck, 174.0ms
image 135/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09595_png.rf.f2ba73226ef1eb918eb6ed38079d90ea.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 1 truck, 173.7ms
image 136/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09598_png.rf.3d6ec787051a3895d2cc99b96300c662.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 2 cars, 1 truck, 175.3ms
image 137/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09600_png.rf.7a705dc70e42ca8f266b31d23375842f.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 4 cars, 1 truck, 174.8ms
image 138/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09609_png.rf.5be75c03fb0e183d73949eaee7aea74b.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 4 cars, 1 backpack, 173.9ms
image 139/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09610_png.rf.ffe992e5790258415830acdbc2f640c5.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 4 cars, 1 truck, 173.7ms
image 140/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09612_png.rf.70fe9178c6e70ffb024da4a986579f22.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 4 cars, 173.8ms
image 141/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09615_png.rf.dd434d830e71f9c35f496403120be549.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 2 cars, 1 truck, 1 traffic light, 174.1ms
image 142/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09618_png.rf.cef06e0e8001b3403ce533aa52f04c7e.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 3 cars, 175.4ms
image 143/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09619_png.rf.ee8cda26e47b4e3fddc4702372ccfc99.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 2 cars, 173.7ms
image 144/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09620_png.rf.8142b54d8c79ae256c91954d6429b21d.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 173.8ms
image 145/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09621_png.rf.bcffe3c53f7af2c8eed1921d97667437.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 3 cars, 1 traffic light, 173.7ms
image 146/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09624_png.rf.78371bf219b7e0d391cfd615277a73c6.jpg: 640x640 2 cars, 1 traffic light, 173.8ms
image 147/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09627_png.rf.0c98638bee2e1ca83fe798704afa3258.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 4 cars, 175.6ms
image 148/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09628_png.rf.7ed1777045097c82d4556b1181e0eca9.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 1 traffic light, 173.8ms
image 149/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09639_png.rf.2b4f6aae5ad401e3f55bb573df415103.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 4 cars, 173.7ms
image 150/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09642_png.rf.318f2a88a4ac410dfe591d5c514f25d1.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 3 cars, 173.9ms
image 151/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09647_png.rf.54795643766df49f93b426f0305c5a0d.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 2 cars, 174.5ms
image 152/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09654_png.rf.3648fca642e9404178fe30b6ae084f57.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 175.6ms
image 153/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09657_png.rf.1ff6a9b227119639d8992e1d5fa8eb40.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 4 cars, 173.7ms
image 154/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09658_png.rf.cf55d26e754abb729f7d656fe913e622.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 2 cars, 1 truck, 173.9ms
image 155/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09660_png.rf.67b091f2b4bcf9e622c38d6c087d5da8.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 4 cars, 176.4ms
image 156/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09664_png.rf.97685d2c31d78f8b6a10a79abdafeae1.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 4 cars, 173.6ms
image 157/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09666_png.rf.8a4eca9347354c503f5e3ef3b26ad122.jpg: 640x640 2 persons, 3 cars, 175.5ms
image 158/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09668_png.rf.5574ec124c328b1cd5892ea9477d6ff2.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 173.9ms
image 159/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09669_png.rf.8e3d904d8bfbf01da76d5de9162955f1.jpg: 640x640 3 cars, 174.2ms
image 160/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09676_png.rf.686d9bad5be73513e12c097ec13073c8.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 1 truck, 175.1ms
image 161/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09677_png.rf.06af75dd3863d08479a33c29b2080db6.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 1 truck, 173.6ms
image 162/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09679_png.rf.6ff89cdcaffd78fff200ec571aae4b10.jpg: 640x640 3 cars, 175.3ms
image 163/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09681_png.rf.6c080a847fd627540ff23b9d430fed6d.jpg: 640x640 3 cars, 173.7ms
image 164/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09683_png.rf.5166c1a4004d5b9b0879cf398d9f86e2.jpg: 640x640 3 cars, 1 suitcase, 173.7ms
image 165/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09688_png.rf.d6f641ea03ab54054c3004bf0dce6e97.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 1 traffic light, 175.5ms
image 166/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09691_png.rf.3b4c0dd805c9913e2a4e3f22fd2874cc.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 173.9ms
image 167/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09696_png.rf.1b365e59f89261a366fbed11bb5c1770.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 175.2ms
image 168/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09697_png.rf.d97ff2fce538d3070cc8f75d3c6e655d.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 173.9ms
image 169/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09700_png.rf.e4e061b52d54e8f3733e576b1dc80f8a.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 173.9ms
image 170/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09702_png.rf.87c99933afaa2329aaf72a2b7599635c.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 175.4ms
image 171/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09703_png.rf.67a0b2d23ccefb0e7649ddcb87ff0001.jpg: 640x640 4 cars, 174.1ms
image 172/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09705_png.rf.9bd3ead27268a7db05d3e4d26f4fe341.jpg: 640x640 3 cars, 173.9ms
image 173/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09706_png.rf.10a428ee4340eada6875ec210a250015.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 173.6ms
image 174/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09715_png.rf.3cbd522a533436d41a62a0411b7ee820.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 173.7ms
image 175/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene09718_png.rf.d870455f822012d818785090941c77d7.jpg: 640x640 1 person, 3 cars, 175.2ms
image 176/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene15712_png.rf.fe211cdb63d359cdebc7dea53ee475d4.jpg: 640x640 12 cars, 1 bus, 1 truck, 1 parking meter, 173.6ms
image 177/178 /yolov5/data/images/scene15715_png.rf.15fbe331f13ea8b104f3a699847c94dd.jpg: 640x640 10 cars, 2 buss, 173.8ms
image 178/178 /yolov5/data/images/zidane.jpg: 384x640 2 persons, 1 tie, 104.7ms
Speed: 3.1ms pre-process, 173.7ms inference, 10.6ms NMS per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
```

It is using CUDA, not TensorRT yet, but from this ([reference from seedstudio](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2022/08/23/faster-inference-with-tensorrt-on-nvidia-jetson-run-yolov5-at-27-fps-on-jetson-nano/)) I expect an average of 50 ms per inference and my result has a poor performance of 170ms

I have tried the same libraries without docker. Similar results:

- MAXN - 130ms
- 5W - 180ms

What could be the cause of the poor performance?

This is from the reference...

[image]

Comment: Can you try again outside of a docker environment (in a `venv` environment for instance) and using the latest versions of PyTorch (1.13), TorchVision and Python (3.10) please?

Comment: @LouisLac I have repeated the same libraries without Docker (a new SD card) and the average result is 130ms, it is still very far from 50ms

Comment: More exactly: 130ms with MAXN mode, 180ms with 5W mode, both without Docker, still with python 3.8.... the reference was with python 3.69

Comment: What bothers me is that in the SeedStudio example they specified a 640x640 input resolution but their camera is only 480x640, which apparently takes precedence over over the former, while on your side you are in 640x640. Could you using 480x640?

Comment: Also, you could try to flash the Jetson Nano again using the latest Nvidia software and upgrading your system packages (`sudo apt upgrade`).

Comment: @LouisLac I have drivers newer than the referenced article..... but the example is retrieving images directly from camera, and I'm getting immages from SD Card.... I'm waiting to receive a compatible usb camera that delivers 640x480 x 30 fps and compare the result.

Comment: Yes, depending on the size of your images and the speed of the SD card, this could be the limiting factor.

Comment: AFAIK you will have to optimize your yolov5 model with tensort in order to achieve good FPS and I think only yolov5n model is best fit for Jetson Nano device.

Answer (score 0):

The clue was to use a USB camera 640x480, this way i'm getting 0.060s average with model yolov5n. The delay was caused by the file system retrieving images from disk.

I had to merge instructions from

https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/YOLOv5-Object-Detection-Jetson/#inference-on-jetson-device

and

https://www.forecr.io/blogs/ai-algorithms/how-to-run-yolov5-real-time-object-detection-on-pytorch-with-docker-on-nvidia-jetson-modules